# Name of a cocktail with orange peel+coconut+lime

Tags: cocktails

Last night, I asked bartender for a cocktail based on orange peel. Then he made a cup of cocktail with orange peel & coconut & lime. It was off sweet taste.

He told me the name of cocktail which is named a after a WoMan chancellor who shut down every bar and pub in her university, and so their students made this cocktail to curse her. But now I can't remember the name...

Is here anybody who knows the name?

Comment: It would help if we knew what was used as a base for the cocktail: rum, whiskey, rye, tequila or vodka?

Comment: If it's named after the woman chancellor who shut down every bar at her university, it's very unlikely you'll find the name without knowing the university she was at! It's probably a local cocktail as opposed to a well known one.

Comment: Do you know the name or the location of the university? That might help in researching the name of this probably local cocktail.